# Как загружать из pandas в pytorch?

Tags: python, pandas, нейронные-сети, pytorch

```
data = pd.read_csv('\\digit-recognizer\\train.csv')
data = np.array(data)

test_data = data[:1000]
train_data = data[1000:10000]

X_batch, y_batch = train_data[:, 1:], train_data[:,0]

X_batch = X_batch.reshape(X_batch.shape[0], 1 ,  28, 28)
X_batch = X_batch / 255

y_batch = y_batch.reshape(y_batch.shape[0], 1)
y_batch = np.int_((np.arange(0,10) == y_batch))

y_batch = torch.from_numpy(y_batch).float()
X_batch = torch.from_numpy(X_batch).float()

X_batch = X_batch.long()
y_batch = y_batch.long()


class ConvNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        # размер исходной картинки 28x28

        # conv 1
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=6, kernel_size=(3,3)) #26x26
        # pool
        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2,2)) #13x13
        # conv 2
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=6, out_channels=9, kernel_size=(4,4)) #10x10
        
        # flatten
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()

        # linear 1
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(900, 100)
        # linear 2
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(100, 10)

    
    def forward(self, x):
        # forward pass сети

        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = self.pool1(x)
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))

        x = self.flatten(x)

        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        
        return x


conv_net = ConvNet()
device = torch.device("cpu")
conv_net = conv_net.to(device)
loss_fn = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()


learning_rate = 1e-3
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(conv_net.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

model.train(True)
model(X_batch.to(device))
```

Получаю

```
RuntimeError: expected scalar type Long but found Float
```

Answer (score 0):

подсказали убрать метод .long() у X_batch

```
    
X_batch = X_batch.long()
y_batch = y_batch.long()
```

Вопрос, почему - остается открытым

Comment: long - это целые числа, вы определитесь, что вы хотите, целые числа или с плавающей точкой, tensorflow не может вас понять https://stackoverflow.com/a/60440460/8324991